# How better use replaceAll?

Tags: java

```
String jparse = [[10, 20, 'stringone', '{gvdfdf}'], [12, 30, 'stringtwo', '{vxcbnn}']]
```

How use replace all, that result was: [{gvdfdf}, {vxcbnn}]

Comment: The code you have posted doesn't make sense. Do you have some real code?

Comment: You didn't even show how you tried to use `replaceAll()`, how should be be able to suggest _improvements_ then?

Comment: Please include an example of your code showing how you are trying to use `ReplaceAll`. This is not a complete question.

Comment: I use jparse.replaceAll(".*(\\{.*\\}).*", "$1"));

Answer (score 0):

I get answer to my question. Maybe this answer will help someone.

```
String jparse = [[10, 20, 'stringone', '{gvdfdf}'], [12, 30, 'stringtwo', '{vxcbnn}']]

String b = jparse.replaceAll("\\[\\d*, \\d*, '\\w*', '(\\{\\w+\\})'\\]", "$1");
```